# NullPointerException while adding an object to an array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

Alright so I'm having a problem with some code that is generating a null pointer exception, meaning that my code is attempting to use a null value where it should be using an object (Straight out of the API). What I'm doing is I have a class called Hotel that has a constructor which assigns a string value to a variable and creates an array of type Room, an object. I know this should be straight forward yet for the life of me I cannot figure this out.

I'll try and keep the code as minimalist as possible:

Constructor for an object, Hotel, that creates a new array of size NUM_ROOMS

**Here are the included updates, I still am stuck with the Null pointer problem unfortunately**

```
public Hotel(String hotelName)
{
    name = hotelName;
    theRoom = new Room[NUM_ROOMS];
}
```

This constructor creates an array of type Room, whose parameters are assigned to the variables

```
public Room(String guestName, int partySize, int bedCountRequired,
        double ratePerDay, int daysStaying)
{
    guest = guestName;
    number = partySize;
    numBeds = bedCountRequired;
    rate = ratePerDay;
    numOfDays = daysStaying;
}
```

This following method is supposed to:

1) create a new instance of the object Room using the supplied parameters

2) assign an array reference to that instance at the index roomsRented (defined as zero when the code is first initialized then increases by one after)

```
public void addReservation(String guestName, int partySize,
        int bedCountRequired, double ratePerDay, int daysStaying)
{
    Room roomHolder = new Room(guestName, partySize, bedCountRequired,
            ratePerDay, daysStaying);

    theRoom[roomsRented] = roomHolder;

    roomsRented++;
}
```

The problem that I am encountering is that

```
theRoom[roomsRented] = roomHolder;
```

is appearing to cause a null pointer exception. I am also getting an error from Eclipse that  the array variable theRoom is unused despite that I use it in the aforementioned method. This leads me to believe that I am not referencing that object correctly. However, I don't know why that reference is incorrect, even if I substitute in theRoom[0], the compiler still gives me a null pointer. I don't see any problems with my array construction which to me means that the only problem that could cause a null pointer exception is if I don't reference any values in my array.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance for any contributions and apologies if the answer is painfully simple.

**EDIT*****
Thank you for your help, the problem with the variable not being found has been resolved but everytime I try and reference the object in the array I still get a nullpointer exception. Here is an example of how I'm trying to reference the array:

```
public double getTotalRentalSales()
{
    // Iterate through the array
    for (int i = 0; i < theRoom.length; i++)
    {
        // sum the amount money received per rental
        totalRate = totalRate + theRoom[i].getRate();
    }
    // Return total
    return totalRate;
}
```

where getRate() is a method that returns the variable rate from the object Room

```
totalRate = totalRate + theRoom[i].getRate();
```

is causing the null pointer in this situation. Is there a problem with my object reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in the constructor you're defining in its scope a variable called theRoom, that means you won't be assigning the value new Room[NUM_ROOMS] to your Hotel class field named **theRoom** but rather to a variable inside the constructor called **theRoom**.

Just remove the type declaration (Room[]) in the constructor and it will work as expected. 
I also suggest that in the future use the **this** keyword to help you avoid this kind of problems.

```
public Hotel(String hotelName)
{
 this.name = hotelName;
 this.theRoom = new Room[NUM_ROOMS];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately Im still getting a null pointer exception from references to the array, for instance

totalRate = totalRate + theRoom[i].getRate();

where getRate() is a method that returns the rate variable described in the Room constructor.

That code still gives me a nullpointer is if my reference is invalid

Comment: Well, creating a new Room[NUM_ROOMS] will create you an array that can store up to NUM_ROOMS of object rooms, but by default each position is initialized by null. So unless you call getTotalRentalSales() when you've rented all the rooms you'll always get an NPE. You want to perform the operation totalRate = totalRate + theRoom[i].getRate(); only until i < roomsRented not until theRoom.length

Comment: Excellent insight there pabrantes, you just facilitated a major "light switch" moment for me there, thanks greatly.

I ended up just changing a method so that every time I made a new reference it increased the counter of some placeholder variable. That way when I called any for loop to manipulate the array, it only advanced as far as elements had been defined for it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in Hotel's constructor:

```
public Hotel(String hotelName)
{
    name = hotelName;
    Room[] theRoom = new Room[NUM_ROOMS];
}
```

You probably have a theRoom instance field, right? The above assignment to theRoom creates a local variable that "hides" (and is independent from) the theRoom instance field, and is lost once the constructor returns. What you want is to initialize the theRoom instance field:

```
public Hotel(String hotelName)
{
    name = hotelName;
    theRoom = new Room[NUM_ROOMS];
}
```

Comment: You are indeed correct that that fix resolved the issue I was having with the variable not being found (thank you for that) except I'm still getting a null pointer exception when I try and use a method that references that array.

I guess the real question is, is it not possible to call a method against an array element?

as an example

totalRate = totalRate + theRoom[i].getRate();

where getRate() is a method that returns the value of a variable, still yields a null pointer exception

Is that an invalid way to call a method against an object in an array?