# Wifi Scanner scanning multiple times

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I am trying to create an app which does 20 scan when I hit the scan button and I get the average rssi value of the signal finally.

My Code is as follows :

```
MainActivity.java

package com.example.scanner;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    WifiManager wifi;
    WifiScanReceiver wifireciever;
    WifiInfo info;
    Button scan, save;
    List<ScanResult> wifilist;
    ListView list;
    String wifis[];
    String name;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        scan=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


        scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                wifi=(WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

                if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()==false){
                    wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);

                }

                wifireciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
                registerReceiver(wifireciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
                wifi.startScan();

            }
        });

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                savedata();

            }
        });


    }

    public class scan_data {
        String SSID;
        String BSSID;
        int lvl;
        int count = 0;
    }


    protected void onPause() {
          unregisterReceiver(wifireciever);
          super.onPause();
       }

    protected void onResume() {
          registerReceiver(wifireciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
          super.onResume();
       }

    class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
          @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
          public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

              wifilist = wifi.getScanResults();
                 info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
                int k = wifilist.size(); 

                 scan_data[] data = new scan_data[k];

             for (int i=0;i<20;i++){
                wifi.startScan();
                wifilist = wifi.getScanResults();

                int l = wifilist.size();

                if (i==0){
                for (int j=0;j<l;k++){
                    data[j].SSID=wifilist.get(j).SSID;
                    data[j].BSSID=wifilist.get(j).BSSID;
                    data[j].lvl=wifilist.get(j).level;
                    data[j].count++;
                }
                }




                else if (i==19){
                for (int j=0;j<l;j++){

                        if (data[j].BSSID.equals(wifilist.get(j).BSSID)){
                            data[j].lvl=data[j].lvl+wifilist.get(i).level;
                            data[j].count++;
                        }

                        data[j].lvl=data[j].lvl/data[j].count;

                        wifis = new String[l];
                         for(int r = 0; r < l; r++){
                             wifis[j]=("\n" + data[j].SSID + "\n AP Address : " +data[j].BSSID + "\n Signal Strength : " + data[j].lvl).toString();
                         }
                  }
                list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,wifis));
             }


                else{
                    for (int j=0;j<l;k++){
                    if (data[j].BSSID.equals(wifilist.get(j).BSSID)){
                        data[j].lvl=data[j].lvl+wifilist.get(i).level;
                        data[j].count++;
                    }
                }
             }

         }


       }
    }
    protected void savedata() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
               File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
               File directory = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "/WIFI_RESULT");
               directory.mkdirs();
               name = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH mm ss").format(new Date());
               File file = new File(directory,name + "wifi_data.txt");

               FileOutputStream fou = new FileOutputStream(file);

               OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fou);
               try {
                   for (int i =0; i < list.getCount(); i++){
                   osw.append(list.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                   }
                   osw.flush();
                   osw.close();
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               } catch (IOException e){
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }   
}
```

My fragment_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/black_hd"
    tools:context="com.example.wifiscanner.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/abc_action_bar_progress_bar_size"
        android:text="Scan" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
        android:text="Save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndriodManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.scanner"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.scanner.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat

```
06-04 00:59:25.940: D/dalvikvm(28589): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 114K, 14% free 6895K/7943K, paused 26ms, total 27ms
06-04 00:59:25.970: I/dalvikvm-heap(28589): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.728MB for 6400016-byte allocation
06-04 00:59:26.150: D/dalvikvm(28589): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 8% free 13144K/14215K, paused 63ms+10ms, total 181ms
06-04 00:59:26.150: D/dalvikvm(28589): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 47ms
06-04 00:59:26.190: D/AbsListView(28589): Get MotionRecognitionManager
06-04 00:59:26.431: D/libEGL(28589): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_rhea.so
06-04 00:59:26.501: D/BRCM_EGL(28589): eglCreateContext() config: 19 context: 0x4a088fb8, VC context 1, Thread 28589
06-04 00:59:26.501: D/BRCM_EGL(28589): eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4a0802f0, VC surface: 1, Thread: 28589
06-04 00:59:26.501: D/BRCM_EGL(28589): eglMakeCurrent(0x4a088fb8, 0x4a0802f0, 0x4a0802f0) Thread: 28589
06-04 00:59:26.511: D/OpenGLRenderer(28589): Enabling debug mode 0
06-04 00:59:31.035: D/AndroidRuntime(28589): Shutting down VM
06-04 00:59:31.035: W/dalvikvm(28589): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414f82a0)
06-04 00:59:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(28589): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 00:59:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(28589): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS flg=0x8000010 } in com.example.scanner.MainActivity$WifiScanReceiver@41ca4fc0
06-04 00:59:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(28589):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:766)
06-04 00:59:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(28589):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-04 00:59:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(28589):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-04 00:59:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(28589):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 00:59:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(28589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
06-04 00:59:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(28589):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 00:59:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(28589):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 00:59:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(28589):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
06-04 00:59:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(28589):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
06-04 00:59:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(28589):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 00:59:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(28589): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 00:59:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(28589):    at com.example.scanner.MainActivity$WifiScanReceiver.onReceive(MainActivity.java:119)
06-04 00:59:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(28589):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:756)
06-04 00:59:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(28589):    ... 9 more
```

I dont know what the error is but I kinda feel its in the BroadcastReciever thing where I code for 20 scans. If you could help me I would be thankful to you..

Comment: What code you have on line 119 on your MainActivity.java file, at onReceive function? The function is longish, for me to guess the reason would be easier with the line number in hand. It is a nullPointer, so sth is null, and you did not check sth != null before calling..

Comment: on line 119 i was checking for scan no. 20 and do somthing. In code it is if (i==19).... I dont think it is null

Comment: if (i==0){
                for (int j=0;j<l;k++){
                    data[j].SSID=wifilist.get(j).SSID;
                    data[j].BSSID=wifilist.get(j).BSSID;
                    data[j].lvl=wifilist.get(j).level;
                    data[j].count++;                                         the line 119 is data[j].SSID=wifilist.get(j).SSID;

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clarifying the line. Your issue is about array initialization: you initialize array of `scan_data` with size `k`, but the content still remains full of `null`s before you say before that specific command that

```
  data[k] = new scan_data();
```

that would initialize the row. After that your code would work for that part.

Another suspicious thing you have is that you iterate with `j` but you add `k++` on every line. That would just not work. AFAIK, you should add `j++`.

Comment: My reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537181/nullpointerexception-while-adding-an-object-to-an-array

Comment: Sorry for responding late, I have done that too but still its showing same error. Is there any problem when get SSID and then put it into string.